# Generate check boxes based on array elements then populate another array based on checked check boxes

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say we have an empty array that we want to populate it based on checked checkboxes :

```
let selected = [];
```

And another array of some person names:

```
let names = ['Joe', 'Mike', 'Sara', 'Jack'];
```

I want to generate checkboxes for each of the `name's` elements first, then I want to add each checked element to the `selected` array.

I can do this with drop-downs (code below) but I have no idea how this could be done with checkboxes:

```js
let dropDown = document.getElementById('names');
let selected = [];
let names = ['Joe', 'Mike', 'Sara', 'Jack'];

// Loop through each of the voices.
names.forEach(function(e, i) {
  // Create a new option element.
  var option = document.createElement('option');

  // Set the options value and text.
  option.value = names[i];
  option.innerHTML = names[i];

  // Add the option to the voice selector.
  dropDown.appendChild(option);
});

// 3 seconds to select the item
setTimeout(function() {

  if (dropDown.value) {
    selected.push(dropDown.value)
  }

  console.log(selected)

}, 3000)
```

```html
<div class="option">

  <label for="voice">US Pronunciation:</label>
  <select name="voice" id="names"></select>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a `div` element containing an `input` and a `label` for each element of the array. Each one of these elements needs to be appended to an existing parent element `option`. You can achieve this by writing down the actual HTML inside back-quotes. Then create an empty element with [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement). Using the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property you can fill this element with the HTML you wrote. Finally append it like you did using [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild):

```
  const html = `
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="${name}" name="${name}">
      <label for="${name}">${name}</label>
    </div>
  `.trim();

  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.innerHTML = html;

  const element = option.appendChild(wrapper.firstChild);
```

Instead of using [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) to loop through your array, I would use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which allows us to create an array of `input` elements on the go. It's the exact same as using a `forEach`... the only difference is you need to return an element in your callback function:

```
const checkboxes = names.map(function(name) {

  const html = `
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="${name}" name="${name}">
      <label for="${name}">${name}</label>
    </div>
  `.trim();

  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.innerHTML = html;

  const element = option.appendChild(wrapper.firstChild);

  return element.querySelector('input');

});
```

So now we have an array called `checkboxes` which holds four `input` elements corresponding to our four names contained in the initial `names` array.

Whenever you need to know the checkboxes that are checked you can filter them out and get the names of the remaining ones. We'll do this using [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and another `map`:

```
checkboxes.filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked)
          .map(checkbox => checkbox.name);
```

---

Here's the full code:

```js
const option = document.querySelector('.option');
const names = ['Joe', 'Mike', 'Sara', 'Jack'];

const checkboxes = names.map(function(name) {

  const html = `
    <div>
      <input type="checkbox" id="${name}" name="${name}">
      <label for="${name}">${name}</label>
    </div>
  `.trim();

  const wrapper = document.createElement('div');
  wrapper.innerHTML = html;

  const element = option.appendChild(wrapper.firstChild);

  return element.querySelector('input');

});

setTimeout(function() {

  const selected = checkboxes.filter(checkbox => checkbox.checked);

  console.log(selected.map(checkbox => checkbox.name));

}, 3000)
```

```html
<div class="option">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi @SaraRee, if you need additional information, don't hesitate.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to add an onClick event handler for the checkboxes and add them to the select that way.. Something like this should get you started:

```js
let dropDown = document.getElementById('names');
let container = document.getElementById('container');
let selected = [];
let names = ['Joe', 'Mike', 'Sara', 'Jack'];

// Loop through each of the voices.
names.forEach(function(e, i) {
  let html = `
    <input onClick="handleCheck('container', 'names')" type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="${i}_${e}" value="${e}">
    <label for="${i}_${e}">${e}</label>
  `;
  container.innerHTML += html;
});

function handleCheck(containerElementId, inputElementId) {
  let containerElement = document.getElementById(containerElementId);
  let select = document.getElementById(inputElementId);
  select.innerHTML = "";
  selected = [];
  containerElement.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]').forEach(el => {
    if(el.checked) {
      select.innerHTML += `<option value="${el.value}">${el.value}</option>`;
      selected.push(el.value);
    }
  })
  console.log("selected", selected);
}
```

```html
<div class="option" id="container">

  <label for="voice">US Pronunciation:</label>
  <select name="voice" id="names"></select>

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer...plus one... your code is complicated for a beginner like me :) and I don't want that drop-down anymore...

Comment: Can you please remove the drop-down and add the names to `selected` array... I can't understand your code...:(

Comment: Done. Is that what you're looking for?